# Custom text in Angular Select

Tags: angular

How can I get a custom text on an Angular Select that doesn't get overwritten?

Consider the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xvmypoldbob) example. I want the word "Toppings" to always stay there whatever I choose from the dropdown and not move. How can this be achieved? The selected items will be displayed somewhere else.

Comment: So you want the word "Toppings" to be present and sticky in the popup panel?

Comment: I think what you want to do is nonstandard UI, thus not supported by the library. You can try a hack, such as making a separate div with position absolute, a white background, and no pointer events, on top of the select field, so that is always says toppings instead of the user selection.

Comment: @DavidMeza yes, it should always be presend and be the only word on that dropdown.

Comment: Maybe create an empty option selected by default ?